# How do I optimise this Python code?

Tags: python, optimization

I'm doing a coding challenge for fun and to work on my skills - some of you may remember the Advent of Code challenge from last December, I'm working through that. I've got this code as the solution to one of the problems, which works, but it's uselessly slow.

```
inp = "1113122113"

def iterate(num):
    pos = 0
    new = ""
    while pos < len(num):
        counter = 0
        d = num[pos]
        for i in range(pos, len(num)):
            if num[i] == d:
                counter += 1
            else:
                break
        new+=str(counter)
        new+=str(d)
        pos += counter
    print len(new)
    return new

for i in range (50):
    inp = iterate(inp)
```

Past iteration 35 or so, it gets to the point where it's taking several minutes for each iteration. The object is to generate a look-and-say sequence - so 1 goes to 11, then 21, 1211, 111221, 3112211 and so on. I need to find the length of the string after the 50th iteration, but it's 360154 characters long after 40 iterations and my code just isn't optimised enough to handle strings that long in a reasonable time. Can anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: Questions about improving working code are a better fit for [codereview.se].

Comment: _"some of you may remember the Advent of Code challenge from last December"_ - I'm sorry but I don't, could you elaborate a bit on what the challenge was? And by the way, this question would be a better fit for  [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's not particularly important, it's a challenge-a-day site that sprang up last year. It's still around, so I decided to work on it some more. You can find it at adventofcode.com, this is the day 10 challenge.

Comment: And thanks for the tip, I'll go ask on Code Review

Comment: I don't like that large range() call in the middle. I usually use range for small for loops, but I have had trouble with generating a really big list from range, when I didn't need it.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Good point for Python 2, but keep in mind that Python 3 `range` yields values on at a time.

Comment: Really? Dang, we really need to get rid of those third party modules that are keeping us at 2.7

Comment: This was being run on Python 2. Would Python 3 have a noticeable speed boost on that then?

Comment: I say yes, although you would get the same improvement by parsing the input once, rather than having a separate internal loop.

Comment: First of all - you need to include clear problem statement in question. Second of all - all these programming challenges are about finding proper algorithm. They are **designed** for brute-force solution to fail. Note that you are not asked for _string_ after n-th iteration, but about _how long that string would be_. This changes problem statement significantly.

Comment: The really expensive part of your code is probably the `range` calls and the `new += str` parts.  Doing strings like this is actually really inefficent.  It would be better to accumulate a list of strings and then join them at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `itertools.groupby` will make this very fast.

```
from itertools import groupby
def next_say(s):
    return ''.join(str(sum(1 for _ in g))+k for k, g in groupby(s))

def iterate(num):
    """Generator that yields the first num iterations"""
    val = '1'
    for i in range(num):
        val = next_say(val)
        yield val
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: instead of wasting space with a unnecessary list, you can get the same result with `sum( 1 for _ in g )`, also you need to convert that to string...

Comment: @Copperfield Good points, I was wondering how to get around that `list` call.